# Error en tokenizar un campo en python

Tags: python, array, nlp

soy nuevo en python y estoy precisando su ayuda.

estoy trabajando con NLP, y quiero clasificar un campo que es string.

**levanto el dataset**

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv",sep=';',encoding='latin-1',error_bad_lines=False)
```

**tokenizo el campo**

```
data['campo']= data['campo'].str.split()
```

**el output es:**

> 1- [Su, inexperto, personal]   2- [Atención, al, cliente]

cuando chequeo tutoriales que existen en internet, a la mayoria, cuando tokeniza les devuelve las palabras separadas con apostrofe.

**ej:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema, es cuando luego quiero vectorizar (`TfidfVectorizer`), me arroja un error y creo que mi problema viene por aca.

Me pueden ayudar? Porque no me quedan los tokens con apostrofe?

EDIT:
Gracias por sus comentarios.

Luego de ejecutar esto, le agrego la posibilidad de vectorizar el campo:

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=5000)
Tfidf_vect.fit(data['campo'])

A partir de aqui, me arroja el error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Pense que venia por el tema del lower, por lo que agregue:

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False ,max_features=5000)
Tfidf_vect.fit(data['campo'])

y a partir de ahi me tira:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Saben que es?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta el error que te arroja el programa? Con apostrofe te refieres a esto? `['stun', 'even',..]`. Si es así, es la representación de un elemento de tipo `str` en una lista.

Comment: Hola damian, lo que muestras no es más que el resultado de imprimir un DataFrame de pandas, es solo cuestión de representación. `str.split` retorna una lista de cadenas y eso es lo que tienes independientemente que se muestre como `[hola]` o `['hola']`, **en eso no está el error**.  Puedes imprimir una de las celdas, por ejemplo `print(data.campo[1])` lo que si te mostrará `['Su', 'inexperto', 'personal']`, que es como Python imprime las listas. Además de mostrar el error como te comenta Borjinha10, añade un ejemplo con una cadena que ocasione este problema y el código que usas para tokenizar.

Comment: EDIT: Ahí agregue el código que ejecuta después. gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer no funciona porque, básicamente la clase `TfidfVectorizer` no recibe una lista o matriz que tenga un **objeto string**. Este solamente recibe matrices, listas o vectores que tengan datos de tipo entero o `int`.

Ahora, hay varios puntos que debes tener en cuenta. Me imagino que lo que deseas hacer es convertir un texto en vectores con el fin de que sea compatible con un algoritmo de inteligencia artificial o machine learning, para ser las especifico, y así poder clasificar un texto con respecto a una bolsa de palabras, la cual paso a explicar a continuación.

`TfidfVectorizer` trabaja sobre un vector de bolsa de palabras, o `Bag of words` de tipo binario. Es decir, si la palabra se encuentra en el corpus al menos una vez, esa dimensión será 1, de lo contrario será 0.

Hay otros tipos de `bag of words`, como la bolsa de palabras por frecuencia, que es la que voy a utilizar para un ejemplo mas adelante.

> **NOTA:** Entiéndase como corpus un conjunto de documentos. En tu caso es el conjunto de cada celda de texto, cada una de ellas es un documento. Esta terminología viene del NLP para procesamiento de textos.

Ahora, aunque puedes utilizar split, hay librerías obtienen todos los tokens de un documento (String), como `SpaCy`, además que tiene tratamientos y modelos para el procesamiento de lenguaje natural para textos.

Para hacer un ejemplo de como utilizar Tf-idf utilice el dataset que clasifica noticias por su titulo. El link lo puedes encontrar [aqui](https://www.kaggle.com/yemregundogmus/reuters-categorized-wire-data).

Luego de obtener los datos de tu dataset con pandas debes de aplicar varias técnicas de normalización de texto, los cuales pueden afectar a los modelos de clasificación. Estas técnicas son las siguientes:

- **Lematizacion:** Reduce una palabra por su morfología.
- **Stemming:** Reduce una palabra o token a su raíz, en español se le conoce como radicalización.

Aunque ambas puedan sonar similares, difieren. La lematizacion se basa en la morfología de la palabra, por lo tanto va a buscar una base lógica de un token. En ingles, la lematizar la palabra *better*, que en español significa mejor que, el resultado va a ser good, o bien. Esto sucede puesto que de la palabra good se deriva better, o de la palabra *bien* se deriva mejor que.

Con `Stemming` es algo diferente, puesto que este encuentra la raíz de una palabra teniendo en cuenta palabras similares, eliminando inflexiones. Por ejemplo, las palabras que están en plural generalmente al aplicar radicalización quedan en singular, o verbos conjugados quedan en infinitivo. Esto a veces no funciona del todo bien, y elimina letras de un token, quedan resultados como: `amor:amo, lenguajes:lengua`.

También hay mas técnicas de normalización, como eliminar las palabras comunes del vocabulario, además de **eliminar signos de puntuación** y **convertir letras mayúsculas a minúsculas**. La primera consiste en eliminar conectores sencillos y palabras que aporten sentido  un texto al leerlo por un humano.

Un ejemplo de esto en código es el siguiente:

```
def normalize(dataset):
corpus = []
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    re = sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ', dataset['headline_text'][i])
    cad = re
    #print(re)
    re = re.lower()
    re = re.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    #stop_words.add('brief')
    re = [ps.stem(word) for word in re if not word in stop_words]
    
    re = ' '.join(re)
    print(cad, re)
    #print(re)
    corpus.append(re)
return corpus
```

En el anterior código aplico `Stemming`, eliminación de números y signos de puntuación por cada token, también convierto todos los caracteres por token a minúsculas y eliminar las palabras comunes o *stop words* en ingles. Utilice la libreria `nltk` para hacer stemming y utilice el modelo *english* para esto. Utilice este lenguaje puesto que el texto del dataset esta en este lenguaje. Esto lo modificas dependiendo del lenguaje.

Ahora, para aplicar TD-IDF debes de tener una **bolsa de palabras**, como había comentado antes. Esto se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
def get_new_dataset(dataset, corpus, tf_idf=False):
    c = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
    vectors_count = c.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
    y = dataset['category'].values
    if tf_idf:
        transformer = TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=False)
        X = transformer.fit_transform(vectors_count).toarray()
        return X, y
    else:
        return vectors_count, y
```

El método anterior hace uso de la clase `CountVectorizer` de la librería `sklearn`. Esta clase permite construir una matriz de frecuencia de tokens por cada documentos. Las filas representan cada documento o string, teniendo la misma cantidad de filas que el conjunto de datos. Ahora bien, a esta clase le puedes pasar la cantidad de características máxima. Lo recomendable es que cada índice de cada fila represente una palabra. Hay mas parámetros que acepta el constructos de esta clase, lo puedes ver en la [documentacion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

La función anterior devolverá una matriz, como te había dicho antes. Esta estructura de datos ahora será tu nuevo dataset, y es el que utilizaras para trabajar con los modelos de ML o de IA necesarios.

Además, si deseas utilizar TF-IDF te devolverá también una matriz, pero mas trabajada, la cual representara que tan relevante es cada token dentro del documento y del corpus en general. Esto se hace aplicando unas formulas, las puedes ver [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf). Puedes ver la documentación de `TfidfVectorizer` [aquí](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html).

Entonces, en resumidas cuentas lo que hice fue explicarte por que te da ese error, algunas cosas que debes de saber para procesamiento y clasificación de textos, y como funciona la clase `TfidfVectorizer` realmente.